# Which tripod heads accept the Arca-Swiss plate system?

Tags: tripod, tripod-heads, quick-release

Can you point me to some brand which build tripod's head which accept the Arca Swiss plates system?

I know Arca have a ball heads, but I want to know if some other companies provides such heads (I guess Manfrotto is not providing such except with adaptor).

Comment: Hi ruffp. Welcome to the site! By convention around here, there's no need to surround your question with greetings — just start asking away. It's a question/answer site, so it's not rude. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

RRS, Kirk, Novoflex, that I know of. Be advised that my Novoflex lens/camera plates are just a tiiiiny bit too narrow to be used with an RRS quick-release tripod mount - the quick-release does not grip them securely and they can slide straight out which rather defeats the point of having the stuff in the first place!

Comment: Actually, these are the brands I know of that makes plates and other stuff for the Arca-Swiss system. RRS and Kirk do make tripod heads, I don't know about Novoflex but a quick-release plate can easily be mounted to most tripod heads anyway.

Comment: And, just to point out: I don't know if Novoflex plates are too small, or if RRS quick-releases are too big, I'm just saying that mix&match may not be a good idea!

Comment: I've used Arca-swiss/RRS/Acratech/Kirk plates on Arca-swiss/RRS/Acratech/Kirk heads w/no problems.  In the circles i move in Really Right Stuff and Kirk are the two big brands.

Comment: I have RRS and Kirk plates that work just great on my Markins Q10.

Comment: It may very well be that Novoflex is the odd one out... I don't know!

Answer (score 4):

Also [Acratech](http://acratech.net/).

Answer (score 4):

I know of Induro, Benro, and Foba (danger -- expensive) as well as Acratech. If budget's a concern, the Induro and Benro AS-compatible heads start at under $200 with a reasonable load limit (that is, over 5kg) and "feel".

Answer (score 2):

Induro make some as well - I bought the BHD1 and was not very happy with its build quality (http://www.vistek.ca/store/ProPhotoTripods/244986/induro-bhd1-tripod-head.aspx)

I can recommend Markins Q10
https://www.ppsna.com/product_info.php/cPath/21/products_id/872?osCsid=f88cae2aac8fc730793d2b132ec8cc40

I have been using it for a couple of years now and I am really happy with it.  You may read people complain that the pano lock is its weakest part.  I agree.  But if you remember to turn it tight - real tight you can get it to lock.

Answer (score 2):

In my (very expensive) experience, Novoflex camera plates are of a slightly smaller height. They are usually held by friction by the slanting sides but that might be at a tiny more elevated position, while still well inside the clamp. When taking pictures and moving the head, the camera assembly may "drop" by this tiny amount. Because the sides are slanting, the lower position implies a loss of grip.  The camera assembly and may then slide out of the mount (in my case out of a Jobu head into a waterfall).